# TeXmaker and El Capitan, Spinning beachball of death

Tags: texmaker, mactex, mac

I upgraded to El Capitan and since then i haven't been able to compile. I found som helt that MacTex have been moved from /usr/texbin to /Library/TeX/texbin/ and changed the paths. I can now compile some of my Tex documents while others makes my computer go into some infinity-loop and overheating...

Differences between the documents i can and can't compile seems to be either if they contain TiKZ or Biblatex? but i'm not sure.[image]

Here is a picture of my setting i TeXmaker:

Solution looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello there! `:)` Could you provide a sample document in which the computer crashes? Sometimes, a small typo in a TikZ document can propagate some odd behaviours. So far, I've got no problems with El Capitan.

Comment: It compiled fine before the update so something isn't as it used to be. Im not sure everything is pointing at the right place.. can u upload a screendump as the one i have ? If they are identical mine should work :)

Comment: I still have troubles also - when you get it done, could you please update your post with a new screendump? Could you maybe take a screen dump of your "Quick Build" as well. I have tried to change it as well - in order to the manual - but still, without luck.

Comment: mine is identical to the picture below. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9fIvj.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: This is what I have done to configure my TexMaker and it has worked. I use Xetex for font and a variety of math tools. As far as I understand it is from Apple's side( the problem) and by adhering to the new OS rules of not to touch User we can make Tex maker run from different root]

This is what I have done to configure my TexMaker and it has worked. I use Xetex for font and a variety of math tools. As far as I understand it is from Apple's side( the problem) and by adhering to the new OS rules of not to touch `/usr` we can make Tex maker run from different root

Comment: Keep in mind that those instructions are for MacTex 2015. If you have an earlier version, you will first have to upgrade your MacTex first. Also, make sure to check the MD5 signature on your downloaded file. Chrome kept on downloading in erroneously and made the install fail. For some weird reason Safari worked.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people have been having issues with MacTeX after upgrading. There's a guide to explain what happened and how to fix it here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

Though it doesn't have much about TeXMaker, the general advice could help, and the author intends to update the document as people provide more information.

Comment: I've seen this, and i have used it to change into the /Library/TeX/texbin/.. but im not sure all of them are set correctly

Comment: I haven't upgraded, so I don't know how to advise you further; sorry, and best of luck!

Comment: `Though it doesn't have much about TeXMaker`? As a matter of fact, it does. In section, 7.4 TEXmaker, they state it clearly replace `usr` with `Library/TeX` and you are set.