# TexStudio not working after updating to Mac OS Sierra

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, mac

Good morning everyone!

I updated my OS to Sierra and TeXstudio seem not to work anymore. Everytime I try to compile something I get the message

> ```
> Error: Could not start the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1
> -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex
> ```

Thank you for your help!

I've changed the path but I'm still getting the same message. Can someone tell me if I changed the path in the rigth way?

[image]

I'm only using pdfLaTeX!

Comment: Have you checked the path? I remember when I upgraded my OS to El Captain, there is a problem with the path. See this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270717/texmaker-and-el-capitan-spinning-beachball-of-death

Comment: You cannot have the installation under `/usr/`. This should not have worked with El Capitan either. There Apple decided to make a change in the security settings, called "Rootless", so only Apple signed application can change in `/usr/` and some other directories. Hence, TeX moved from `/usr/texbin/` to `/Library/TeX/texbin/`. For more about the change in El Capitan see e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if perhaps you need:

```
/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

That worked for me!

Comment: Great, you were right (sorry, I'm seeing the comment only now).
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I have TS in Sierra and use PDFLaTeX. My path is

```
"/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Note the quotes!!